# Apache Solr on Appfog

Tags: java, apache, solr, appfog

I am very new to Apache Solr and I am trying to deploy it on Appfog application running the Java runtime. I can deploy the start page: [sga-search.aws.af.cm](http://sga-search.aws.af.cm), but nothing else will work. Could someone please direct me as to how can I go about deploying this???

Note: Appfog does not permit SSHing into the server.

Thank you for your time!